# New users and upvoting

Tags: feature-request, new-users, voting

New users can't vote until they have 15 rep. Wouldn't it make sense that they can at least vote on the answers to their own questions, even if they don't have the 15 rep yet?

For instance in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/72000/28009) OP has to say thanks in comment, but couldn't upvote.

Answer (score 5):

I can appreciate your sentiment although I suspect one reason the system has been setup that way is to prevent sockpuppet accounts easily voting each other up. You get +15 for an accepted answer but unlike voting which is anonymous it's obvious who accepted an answer making it easy to spot suspicious behaviour between accounts.

Once or twice I've seen low-quality answers from a new user being quickly accepted on SE sites. On one of those occasions I noticed the account was later deleted so I assume a moderator had noticed the same (or had been flagged about it). I believe that detailed voting information is not available to anyone outside SE staff so that wouldn't be possible to identify if votes were used for that purpose.

Another issue is that new users may not be aware of what constitutes a good answer. It may be the answer is just plain wrong and they don't know it or it may be something that is useful to them but doesn't meet guidelines for a good answer, for example "look **here** for the answer".

The latter may be of slightly less concern but with an upvote on an answer being +10 and a downvote being -2 it could end up rewarding users that quickly post low-quality answers that more experienced users wouldn't consider upvoting.

Comment: I would consider the second case, we are relatively good at detecting vote fraud and rings.

Answer (score 4):

A good question almost guarantees at least 3 upvotes, in which case you understand the system and contributed enough to vote for others that do. If you have not garnered 15 reputation somehow, probably one of the lowest hurdles, we trust you to note who fixed your issue, but you are not yet ready to judge quality of answers.

Answer (score 2):

His way to recognize the answer is to accept it, until he has enough reputation to upvote it.

Comment: But he can only accept 1 answer. What if others are also useful? (Some users just ask one question and never get to 15 reputation)

Comment: @amadeus If some user comes to the site, asks just one question, then goes away, that person isn't a valuable long-term asset to the site anyway, I'd venture. Hence, permitting such persons to upvote is not really worthwhile, is it? It doesn't take much effort to get to the reputation required to legitimately upvote as per the site settings.